# The member "AddNewDevice" is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Window (WPF) using the Fluent.Ribbon ribbon control.
In said ribbon, I have buttons which perform different tasks.
For the commands, I created a static class, containing read-only properties returning the commands.

For the first of the buttons, this method worked perfectly, however, the second command doesn't seem to be found.
I used the exact same syntax I used for the first command, but I keep getting the above error.

I've tried cleaning the solution/build, building the solution and debugging. All to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
<Fluent:RibbonGroupBox Header="Device Operations">
    <Fluent:Button Command="cmd:MainWindowCommands.SearchForNewDevices" Header="Search for Devices" Icon="{DynamicResource searchForDevices}" LargeIcon="{DynamicResource searchForDevicesLarge}" />
    <Fluent:Button Command="cmd:MainWindowCommands.AddNewDevice" Header="Add Device" Icon="{DynamicResource addDevice}" LargeIcon="{DynamicResource addDeviceLarge}" /> <!-- This is where the error occurs -->
</Fluent:RibbonGroupBox>
```

And here's the class containing the commands:

```
using System;

namespace Beatsleigher.eMMCDumper.Commands {

    using Beatsleigher.eMMCDumper.ViewModels;
    using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;

    public static class MainWindowCommands {

        private static RelayCommand searchForNewDevicesCommand;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the search for new devices command.
        /// Created by: Beatsleigher
        /// At:               12.06.2015, 11:18
        /// On:              BEATSLEIGHER-PC
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The search for new devices command.
        /// </value>
        public static RelayCommand SearchForNewDevices {
            get {
                return searchForNewDevicesCommand == null ? searchForNewDevicesCommand = new RelayCommand(MainWindowVM.Instance.SearchForDevicesExecute) : searchForNewDevicesCommand;
            }
        }

        private static RelayCommand addNewDeviceCommand;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the add new device command.
        /// Created by: Beatsleigher
        /// At:               12.06.2015, 22:35
        /// On:              BEATSLEIGHER-PC
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The add new device.
        /// </value>
        public static RelayCommand AddNewDevice {
            get {
                return addNewDeviceCommand == null ? addNewDeviceCommand = new RelayCommand(MainWindowVM.Instance.AddNewDevice) : addNewDeviceCommand;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!